# how to request last segment of url in Flask

Tags: flask

I feel like the answer is simple, yet I can't seem to figure it out. I have a URL:

> http://127.0.0.1:5000/fight_card/fight/5

And I'm trying to use just the "5" in my code as that is the ID for the current fight in the SQL table. So far, I've tried

```
fight = Fight.query.filter_by(id=request.path).first()
```

However that returns:

```
fight_card/fight/5
```

Is there any way I can use "request" to target just the 5? Thank you in advance!

Comment: [This](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#variable-rules) should get you going.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include a variable, `current_fight_id`, in your route definition. You can then access that variable in your view function.

```
@app.route('/fight_card/fight/<current_fight_id>')
def fight_route(current_fight_id):
   print(current_fight_id) # use variable in route
```

Alternatively, you could use the approach you're using but modify the string that's returned. If you have a string:

```
endpoint = "fight_card/fight/5" # returned by your current code
```

You can access the five (current_fight_id) with:

```
current_fight_id = endpoint.split("/")[-1] # grab the segment after the last "/"
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

`request.path` would give you: `/fight_card/fight/5`.  Then, you can `split('/')` to get a list of the parts.